# WP7 MultiScaleImage getting images from Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, multiscaleimage

I want to create a similar control to that of the Bing Maps control (from which I can see it uses the MultiScaleImage) but I have all of my images stored in a compressed format in local isolated storage.

I know of the MultiScaleTileSource class, but from what I have seen that just returns to the MSI a collection of URI's not the images themselves...

Anyone had any any luck with this type of thing?

Comment: I'm facing similar issue now. Did you find any solution for that ?

Comment: sorry no, not in the end...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SharpMap: http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/.

It comes with source code (http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), mentions Silverlight and certainly looks like it might be a winner!